# Prevent 0x800401D3 CLIPBRD_E_BAD_DATA Error

Tags: c#, .net, x86, clipboard

Upon running the below code, every so often I can get an error

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Data on clipboard is
> invalid (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401D3 (CLIPBRD_E_BAD_DATA))

I *handle* the error by the tried and true `try-catch` block, which is fine for my needs<strike>, but the app goes into a state where it either hard exits or the GUI becomes unresponsive and the app has to be killed from the task manager</strike> (*I believe the hard exit is due to a main window inadvertantly being closed upon viewing the error*).

The code checks for valid data `ContainsData(DataFormats.Text)` and if its ok, extracts the text and tries to determine if the text is a pathed file.

Is there a way to prevent the error in the first place? If there is no valid text, I do not need to do the process of checking the clipboard.

**Code**

```
try
{
     var doesClipboardHaveText = Clipboard.ContainsData(DataFormats.Text);

    if (doesClipboardHaveText)
    {
         var pathString = Clipboard.GetText(); // <- Exception Thrown here.

        if (pathString.IndexOfAny(System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars()) == -1)
        {
            contains = pathString.Split(new char[] { ',' })
                              .Any(File.Exists);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.clipboard?view=netcore-3.1