# Clipboard.GetText() throwing exception: OpenClipboard Failed

Tags: c#, moq, clipboard

I have a very simple UI test using **Moq Framework** and **Appium**, where I am trying to test a **Copy** command. I have the following code:

```
    [TestMethod, STAThread]
    public void VerifyCopyCommand()
    {
        Clipboard.Clear();

        // Arrange
        //---Some code to get the Context Menu
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        var copyItem = (contextMenu.FindElementsByClassName("MenuItem").Where(item => item.Text == "Copy")).First();
        
        // Act
        copyItem.Click();
        Thread.Sleep(500); 
        
        // Assert
        var clipboard = Clipboard.GetText();
        //var clipboard = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
```

**PROBLEM:** `Clipboard.GetText()` is keep throwing an exception as shown in the screenshot below:

> **System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException**: 'OpenClipboard Failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401D0 (CLIPBRD_E_CANT_OPEN))'

[image]

**NOTE:** If I execute the `Clipboard.GetText()` statement in the **Quick Watch** Window of Visual Studio then, the statement executes and I am able to see the expected text in it.

Comment: Add the full exception

Comment: You can only access the clipboard from an STA thread. Is `VerifyCopyCommand()` possibly being called from an MTA thread?

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Tried to use `[TestMethod, STAThread]` but still same issue

Comment: I've run into a different Com Exception, and have never been able to track it down. [c# - Prevent 0x800401D3 CLIPBRD\_E\_BAD\_DATA Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64211035/prevent-0x800401d3-clipbrd-e-bad-data-error)

Comment: Maybe the clipboard is kept open by `copyItem` so you therefore you cannot copy from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is happening because you cannot access the clipboard from an MTA thread, only from an STA thread.

If this is the case you can fix it by explicitly starting an STA thread from which to call `Clipboard.GetText()`.

For example:

```
public static string? GetClipboardText()
{
    string? result = null;

    var thread = new Thread(() => { result = Clipboard.GetText(); });
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
    thread.Join();

    return result;
}
```

Can you try calling that method in the unit test instead of calling `Clipboard.GetText()` directly to see if that fixes it?

Comment: Worked! Is there any other simpler/shorter way to achieve this e.g. specifying `STAThread` somehow.

Comment: "you cannot access the clipboard from an STA thread" why?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev Sorry, there was a typo - it should have said "you cannot access the clipboard from an MTA thread". Now fixed.

Comment: @skm As far as I know, Appium always runs the test methods in an MTA thread, so the easiest way to run code from those methods in an STA thread is as shown above. Note that NUnit has the `[RequiresThread(ApartmentState.STA)]` attribute that you can use for this.